# How do I divide each element in a list by an int using function

Tags: function, division

I have a dictionary that contains lists as value, and I want to divide each element in those lists on constant, how can I do that using a def function?!

Comment: What language are you using? I'm going to guess Python, by the `def` keyword and dictionary, but in future, specify in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using python and that I got your question, simple way of doing that:

```
import numpy as np
def divide(input_list, dividend):
  return list(np.array(input_list) / dividend)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use something like:

```py
CONSTANT_K = 2
dict = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4 }

for value in dict.values():
    quotientResult = value / CONSTANT_K
    # do whatever you want with the quotient result here
```

Where `CONSTANT_K` is your constant. Then, you iterate through your dictionary values in a for loop. The loop takes each value in the dictionary and divides it by the constant. You can handle the values inside of the for loop, or you can store them inside a new dictionary or array.

You can put this into a `def` function by doing:

```py
CONSTANT_K = 2
dict = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4 }

def divideDict(k, dictA):
    for value in dict.values():
        quotientResult = value / CONSTANT_K
        # do whatever you want with the quotient result here

divideDict(CONSTANT_K, dict)
```

Where `divideDict()` is your function. If you're looking for a dictionary containing lists, you'll have to loop through the lists as well:

```py
CONSTANT_K = 2
dict = { 'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [5, 6], 'd': [7, 8] }

def divideDict(k, dictA):
    for value in dict.values():
        for val in value:
            quotientResult = val / CONSTANT_K
            # do whatever you want with the quotient result here

divideDict(CONSTANT_K, dict)
```